# How to start an Ignite cluster with persistence enabled on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I have an Ignite setup where we're trying to start several Ignite nodes, all of which are meant to hold data (no clients), with persistence enabled because we want to be able to restart nodes without losing their data.

Here's most of the configuration we're doing (this code runs in all nodes):

```kotlin
val leader = "${setting.masterHost}:${configuration.clusterPortRange.initialPort}"

_logger.debug("Configuring Apache Ignite Cluster Discovery using Leader: {}", leader)

val ipFinder = TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder().apply {
    setAddresses(listOf(leader))
}

val igniteDiscoverySpi = TcpDiscoverySpi().apply {
    joinTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(configuration.clusterJoinTimeout.toLong()).toMillis()
    localPort = configuration.clusterPortRange.initialPort
    localPortRange = configuration.clusterPortRange.portCount
    this.ipFinder = ipFinder
}

val igniteCommunicationSpi = TcpCommunicationSpi().apply {
    messageQueueLimit = 128
    socketReceiveBuffer = 4096
    socketSendBuffer = 4096
    idleConnectionTimeout = 60_000
}

val config = ApacheIgniteConfiguration().apply {
    // The start method must not block until the cluster is joined because we'll activate the cluster
    // only after the start method finishes running. This setting ensure joining the cluster will
    // be delayed so it only does that when we explicitly activate the grid.
    clusterStateOnStart = ClusterState.INACTIVE

    igniteInstanceName = configuration.id()
    consistentId = configuration.serverInformation.id
    clientConnectorConfiguration = clientConnectorConfig
    discoverySpi = igniteDiscoverySpi
    communicationSpi = igniteCommunicationSpi
    isClientMode = false
    isPeerClassLoadingEnabled = false
    gridLogger = Slf4jLogger()
    workDirectory = distributedCacheWorkingDirectory(configuration.id())
    sslContextFactory = clusterConfiguration?.let(::createTlsContextFactory)

    // enable persistence to avoid losing all data on node restart or config changes
    dataStorageConfiguration = DataStorageConfiguration().apply {
        defaultDataRegionConfiguration.isPersistenceEnabled = true

        // See https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/perf-and-troubleshooting/persistence-tuning#pages-writes-throttling
        isWriteThrottlingEnabled = true
    }
}

_logger.debug("Starting Distributed Cache (data-source ID={})", configuration.id())

val ignite = try {
    Ignition.start(config)
}

// now that the Grid has started and is fully configured, we can activate it
ignite.cluster().state(ClusterState.ACTIVE)
```

This works in Docker compose... most of the time at least.

When running in Kubernetes, however, we see errors related to connection issues during the `start()` call... that's not expected because it shouldn't be trying to join a cluster until the cluster has been activated in the last line. At least that's our expectation given the [documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/baseline-topology#baseline-topology-in-persistent-clusters) - and the fact it works, except for some reason, in Kubernetes (I am testing on Docker Kubernetes).

I know the nodes can connect fine because I can make connections in a shell and because the Ignite cluster starts up properly if persistence is disabled.

How can I make sure Ignite starts up correctly even when persistence is enabled?

Stacktraces:

- on startup

```
2022-12-01T08:57:18:558+0000 WARN    {managed-object-init-2} org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi - Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (make sure IP finder addresses are correct and firewalls are disabled on all host machines): [curity-idsvr-admin-svc/10.97.163.71:47500]
```

> As I mentioned above, the node can reach the host/IP and port just fine... it doesn't work in this case because it seems Ignite simply has not started listening on the port yet.

- one minute later (which is the `joinTimeout`):

```
2022-12-01T08:58:18:592+0000 ERROR   {managed-object-init-2} org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal%ignite - Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=o.a.i.i.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager]
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to start SPI: TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, addressFilter=null, sockTimeout=5000, ackTimeout=5000, marsh=JdkMarshaller [clsFilter=org.apache.ignite.marshaller.MarshallerUtils$1@df51269], reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=0, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:281) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:1089) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1766) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1147) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1757) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1679) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1121) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:657) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:579) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to connect to any address from IP finder within join timeout (make sure IP finder addresses are correct, and operating system firewalls are disabled on all host machines, or consider increasing 'joinTimeout' configuration property): [curity-idsvr-admin-svc/10.97.163.71:47500]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1408) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1120) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:472) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2212) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:278) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Multiple connection attempts failed.
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1392) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1120) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:472) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2212) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:278) ~[?:?]
    Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message to address [addr=curity-idsvr-admin-svc/10.97.163.71:47500, msg=TcpDiscoveryJoinRequestMessage [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=5e078ada-fcf2-4810-8de8-87559ba76aa3, consistentId=idsvr-admin-Cxw8n6UM, addrs=ArrayList [10.1.0.40, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [curity-idsvr-admin-86dc6d9bcc-k7w42/10.1.0.40:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=0, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1669885038513, loc=true, ver=2.14.0#20220929-sha1:951e8deb, isClient=false], dataPacket=org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.internal.DiscoveryDataPacket@3630067f, super=TcpDiscoveryAbstractMessage [sndNodeId=null, id=a1c87ecc481-5e078ada-fcf2-4810-8de8-87559ba76aa3, verifierNodeId=null, topVer=0, pendingIdx=0, failedNodes=null, isClient=false]]]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.exceptionWithSuppressed(IgniteUtils.java:10015) ~[?:?]
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: But the error is about connectivity issues, It doesn't look to be related to persistence. But, enabling persistence might cause slower startup due to binary recovery, etc.

Comment: "hat's not expected because it shouldn't be trying to join a cluster until the cluster has been activated in the last line" - that's not true, activation has nothing about that logic. In short, it allows updates, but before that it is super important to have all the baseline nodes up, connected, and running. I.e. connectivity must happen on ignite.start() call.

Comment: Have you tried dynamic KubernetesIpFinder instead of the static one?

Comment: We just cannot see how connectivity issues can be the problem. The Ignite server starts listening on the expected port, the node appears to not be able to connect on itself (as the addresses we add to the IP discovery resolves to the same node). Interestingly, if we disable persistence AND use the `TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder`, the cluster works.

Comment: Well, I can think of how it might be related to persistence. I.e. the only changed configuration is - enabled persistence to the data region, no changes to IPfinder or other properties, correct? If you clean the node or disable persistence, everything goes well, right? And the issue happens only when you have the data already? I.e. if you do a fresh restart or wipe cleaning /db folder, there are still no issues, the nodes can connect to each other?

Comment: If so, I suspect there might be a long binary recovery for one of the nodes. That last more that the configured joinTimeout or another network-related timeout. In other words, my guess is - Ignite's internal take more time than a network timeout on another node, making it impossible to join the topology. But to say precisely, I'd like to check the logs from the nodes + their configuration.

Comment: I still do not recommend you using non-shared (static) IpFinders in your configuration, they behave differently and are not the best choice for dynamic envs like K8s, check the following Java docs for more details https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/TcpDiscoveryIpFinder.html#isShared--

Comment: I understand, but we're embedding Ignite on our server. We already form a cluster of nodes based on a single admin. We want to make Ignite also use the same topology so we treat one of the Ignite nodes as a master (For discovery purposes). I was able to get it working using `isShared = true` as you suggested, and this works with persistence enabled. There are some other problems but they seem unrelated. How can we get in touch to get "formal" support so we can give you more details?

Comment: I think you should be contacted soon, thanks. Good, if you have it working now.